# Make full screen for Turbo C++ in Windows Vista/7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, c++

How to make full screen for Turbo C++ in Windows Vista/7?

Comment: please please use some other compiler . visual studio /eclipse /netbeans and many more are available for free take ur pick. dont tell me u are using it for the blue screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a full-screen console, you will need to install and use old XP display drivers instead of WDDM drivers.